# In the Ex-Heroes universe, has the source of powers been explained?

Tags: zombie, super-hero, ex-heroes

In Peter Clines's *[Ex-Heroes](http://peterclines.com/books/)* series, super-heroes seem, as best I can tell, super-powers just sort of showed up. One day, there were no super-powered individuals and then suddenly, they were coming out of the woodwork (there are obvious exceptions such as Cairax, Corpse Girl, and Captain Freedom, who either engineered their powers or had them engineered into them). Has there ever been an explanation, possibly in supplemental stories or Clines's blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I would go with the standard super-hero tropes since in the first book, The Mighty Dragon gains his powers after a small meteor strikes a university's chemical repository killing everyone but him. He, after recovering is slowly transformed into his superheroic and less than human self.

**From page five of Ex-Heroes:**

> It'd been about three months since the incident at the lab. "Incident" is how they kept referring to it in the news and in the therapy sessions, and the word had been beaten into my head by constant use. There'd been a lot of publicity around me at first as the sole survivor of the explosion, but the news quickly shifted to focus on the twelve people who had died and the scandal of poor chemical storage. Of course, who could blame the university for not designing their building to resist a meteor strike?

**The Mighty Dragon goes on to describe:**

> I also read lots of articles about that meteorite and odd wavelengths of electromagnetic energy it threw off. Lots of stuff on Wired news about it for a few weeks. I think NASA ended up with it, farmed a ton of work out to MIT and then it just sort of dropped off the radar.

**It is hard to find a more trope filled origin story than this:**

- A mysterious meteor with strange radiation (See: Smallville's Meteor Freaks)
- The meteor crashes into a chemical repository whose unknown effects mutate the sole survivor (The Flash, Swamp Thing, Solomon Grundy, all affected by accidental exposure to chemicals and changed).
- The Mighty Dragon goes on to describe his slow transformation, gaining lizard-like skin and gliding abilities. (See: The Lizard, Man-Bat)
- His origin is complete when he interrupts some thugs robbing a woman and is shot for his troubles. He is surprised at how much it hurts to be shot but surprised to be alive and with a cough, he sprays a gout of flame at them. The woman thanks him and the Mighty Dragon was born.

**Standard superhero fare and I doubt the other origins are too far from the classic superhero themes.**

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I'd forgotten that George had gone through "the Incident".